# Matching a certain aspect of a ping

Tags: ruby, ping

I'm writing a program that has to ping a printer, however I don't like the ping information I think it looks sloppy:

```
PING laser32 (10.208.7.13) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from laser32 (10.208.7.13): icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.837 ms

--- laser32 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.837/0.837/0.837/0.000 ms
```

Is there a way I can match just this `1 packets transmitted` and get rid of the rest?

What I've tried so far is:

- `[/1 packets transmitted/]`
- `gsub` <= Didn't help at all

Source:

```
def ping
  send = system("ping -c 1 #{@printer}")
  send.match[/1 packets transmitted/]
  puts send
  # case
  # when send != "1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss"
  #   send_print_jobs
  # else
  #   raise LoadError.new("Printer: #{@printer} failed to ping, check network connection")
  # end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`Kernel#system` returns [`true`/`false`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system). To receive a command output, use [backticks or `%x`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60):

```
`ping -c 1 #{@printer}`[/1 packets transmitted/]
#⇒ 1 packets transmitted
```